# how to separate a col into multiple cols

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this: it has 6 rows, and I would like to put each row into cols which can be separate by "|" . In my example, 6 cols.

What should I do in order to get a df that looks like:

[image]

col name can be col1-col6.

```
df <-c("*| Characteristic | class1 \n(N=2)\nn (%) | class2 \n(N=4)\nn (%) | class3 \n(N=2)\nn (%) | class4 \n(N=6)\nn (%) | class\nOverall\n(N=14)\nn (%) | ", 
"*| Age (years) [2] |  |  |  |  |  | ", "*|   n |    2 |    4 |    2 |    6 |   14 | ", 
"*|   Mean (SD) |   64.0 (5.66) |   65.3 (11.41) |   29.0 (7.07) |   68.8 (14.47) |   61.4 (17.59) | ", 
"*|   Median |   64.0 |   68.5 |   29.0 |   69.5 |   64.0 | ", 
"*|   Min, Max |   60, 68 |   50, 74 |   24, 34 |   45, 84 |   24, 84 | "
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr::separate` will separate into columns:

```
library(tidyr)

data.frame(x = df) |>
  separate(x, into = paste0("col", 1:8), sep = "\\|")
```

From here you can drop columns and do additional formatting.

**Output**

```
  col1              col2                    col3                    col4                    col5                    col6                            col7 col8
1    *   Characteristic   class1 \n(N=2)\nn (%)   class2 \n(N=4)\nn (%)   class3 \n(N=2)\nn (%)   class4 \n(N=6)\nn (%)   class\nOverall\n(N=14)\nn (%)      
2    *  Age (years) [2]                                                                                                                                      
3    *                n                       2                       4                       2                       6                              14      
4    *        Mean (SD)             64.0 (5.66)            65.3 (11.41)             29.0 (7.07)            68.8 (14.47)                    61.4 (17.59)      
5    *           Median                    64.0                    68.5                    29.0                    69.5                            64.0      
6    *         Min, Max                  60, 68                  50, 74                  24, 34                  45, 84                          24, 84
```